# How to further parse a nested dictionary in a json file to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

I have a very large json file which I want to convert into a dataframe with a desired structure explained later in the question.

A few records of the sample json are shown here:

```
JsonRecords = {
         'rec1': 
              {
                'words':[  ['A', 'B', 'C', '.'],  
                           ['D', 'E', 'F','.']],                           
                  'Ids':[  [0, 1],  
                           [2, 3]],

               'unique':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],

                'ments': {
                          "(0, 1)":{
                                    "A1": [0], 
                                    "A2": [0,1], 
                                    "A3": [1], 
                                    "A4": [1,0], 
                                    "A5": [0] 
                                   },                          
                         "(2, 3)": {
                                    "A1": [0], 
                                    "A2": [0], 
                                    "A3": [1],  
                                    "A5": [0] 
                                   }                  
                          }
              },  
      'rec2': 
             {
               'words':[   ['We', 'us', 'them', '.'], 
                           ['is', 'it', 'us''.'    ]], 
                 'Ids':[   [4, 5],  
                           [6, 7]],
              'unique':[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                                
               "ments": {
                         "(4, 5)": {
                                    "A1": [0], 
                                    "A2": [0], 
                                    "A3": [0], 
                                    "A4": [0] 
                                   },                          
                        "(6, 7)": {
                                    "A1": [0], 
                                    "A2": [0],  
                                    "A4": [0,0], 
                                    "A6": [0,1]
                                  }
                     }
             }, 
      'rec3':             
     ..... more records
}
```

I parsed the json sample with the following code:

```
  import pandas as pd
  #import json

  all_data = []
  for k, v in JsonRecords.items():
     words, Ids, unique, ments = v['words'], v['Ids'], v['unique'], v['ments']
     for t, val, m in zip(words, Ids, ments.items()):
       all_data.append({
        'records': k,
        'words': ' '.join(t),
        'Ids': val,
        'unique': unique,
        'ments': m            
        })
  #print(all_data)
  df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
  df.to_csv('myData.csv', encoding='utf-8')
  print(df.head())
```

When I run the code, I get the following dataframe strucutre:

```
 records     words          Ids         unique                    ments                    
  rec1      A, B, C.       [0, 1]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]   ('(0, 1)', {'A1': [0], 'A2': [0, 1], 'A3': [1], 'A4': [1, 0], 'A5': [0]})                          
  rec1      D, E, F.       [2, 3]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]   ('(2, 3)', {'A1': [0], 'A2': [0], 'A3': [1], 'A5': [0]})                          
  rec2      We, us, them.  [4, 5]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]   ('(4, 5)', {'A1': [0], 'A2': [0], 'A3': [0], 'A4': [0]})                            
  rec2      is, it, us.    [6, 7]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]   ('(6, 7)', {'A1': [0], 'A2': [0], 'A4': [0, 0], 'A6': [0, 1]})                        
  rec3
```

As shown above, I am not able to further parse the 'ments' dictionary according to the 'Ids' and 'words' columns which should also be repeated by parsing the 'ments' dictionary and its nested values.

The dataframe structure I want from this nested json is shown below.

```
Records       words          Ids     unique                 ments    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
  rec1      A, B, C.       [0, 1]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]     [0, 1]     0   0   1   1   0 
  rec1      A, B, C.       [0, 1]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]     [0, 1]         1       0      
  rec1      D, E, F.       [2, 3]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]     [2, 3]     0   0   1       0  
  rec1      D, E, F.       [2, 3]   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]     [2, 3]                       
  rec2      We, us, them.  [4, 5]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]     [4, 5]     0   0   0   0     
  rec2      We, us, them.  [4, 5]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]     [4, 5]                       
  rec2      is, it, us.    [6, 7]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]     [6, 7]     0   0       0       0
  rec2      is, it, us.    [6, 7]   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]     [6, 7]                 0       1
  rec3 
  ....... more records
```

I will appreciate some help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use apply and json_normalize

```
def getMents(value):
    return value[0]
def getJson(value):
    return value[1]
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df['json'] = df['ments'].apply(getJson)
jsonData = pd.json_normalize(df['json'])
df['ments'] = df['ments'].apply(getMents)
for col in jsonData.columns.values:
    df[col] = jsonData[col]
new_df = df[0:0]
results= df[0:0]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    maxCount = 0
    for col in jsonData.columns.values:
        if isinstance(row[col],list):
            maxCount = max(maxCount,len(row[col]))
    for i in range(0,maxCount):
        count = len(new_df)
        new_df.loc[count] = row
    
        for col in jsonData.columns.values:
            if isinstance(new_df[col][i],list):        
                try:
                    new_df.loc[i,col]= new_df[col][i][i]
                except IndexError:
                    new_df.loc[i,col]=None
    results = pd.concat([results,new_df])
    new_df = df[0:0]

results
```

Comment: ! Thanks for your help. I am getting columns A1 to A6 but again they are nested and the value pairs are on the same row. The format i mentioned is different. for example if A1 has two values like [0,1]. Then the first value should be on the first row and second value on second row as indicated in the required dataframe without ''[]" as i mentioned above in the question.

Comment: sorry! I edited the code. It may not be the best answer, but it produces the desired output @ToBeEXP

Comment: Thanks alot @sepideh_ssh. I will check it with the original json file if it is working..

Comment: @spedieh_ssh@ I am accepting the answer. The original file i have is extremely huge so it takes a lot of time and very slow but still it provides the desired format but with some unexpected values in some rows that do not understand. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @ToBeEXP  if unexpected values in some rows are None and Nan you can remove them by `results.replace(numpy.nan, '', regex=True)` and replace  `new_df.loc[i,col]=None` in my answer to `new_df.loc[i,col]='' `

Comment: @ToBeEXP for improve execution time you can chunk your data an run each part as a subprocess .

Comment: Thanks, that is clear and not an issue. In some rows, instead of getting 0's and 1's values as the values of A1 to lets say A500, I am getting some rows that does not make sense but i think i can remove them with some conditions its not an issue. Thanks a lot for taking time and help me out :)